# Site very slow when viewed from china

Tags: web-hosting, dns, optimization

My site is very slow when viewed from china.

I have used this tool for testing:
http://www.dotcom-monitor.com/WebTools/website-speed-test.aspx

This is the result

[image]

Shangai - waterfall

[image]

only the DNS resolution has cost 4 seconds

how can I make things better for Chinese users?

the performance of the site are generally good and I tried to optimize all the best

[image]

Comment: Could be the great firewall

Comment: Based on the other great firewall they built, the one that can be seen from space, the one to keep the Mongols out, I suspect that John is right!

Comment: Where is your site located? TBH, the few sites I've tried in that tool (that are admittedly located outside of China) all give very slow (30+ seconds) for the "Shanghai, China" server test.

Comment: @w3d in italy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well its not your site, its China's internet service layout, which has to jump through hoops to get even get to US DNS Servers. Furthermore, I don't know how 'free' the Internet surfing is there, meaning if it's being monitored by the government, which would undoubtedly further slow its response times. Many factors can be attributed to your site being slow from 'China', none of which you can control, unless you create an http://www.yoursite.cn/ domain and host it on Chinese servers, simply mirroring your site all in Chinese. Not a bad idea, if your market is Chinese in nature, there's a lot of people in China.

Comment: I just register my domain (*. com) at a Chinese DNS service?

Comment: Not sure if a quicker DNS resolution of your domain name alone, would significantly speed up the loading of all your site's content.

Comment: I notice that I lose 4 seconds to resolve dns ...

Comment: But DNS results get cached, this should only take 4sec for 1 file (per IP), for the first load.